# Flutter Bloc get previous State

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I would like to get the value of a previous state.

I am working through the timer example of the Flutter Bloc tutorial. I decided to add an extra feature and created an input field, where the user can select their own time. The probelm is, when I reset my Timer the set time was resplaced with the default value.

My solution is to overwrite the _duration in the _onChanged, but it kind of feels like an Antipattern.

would there be a cleaner solution or a way, where i can get the values after the reset, to get a previous state?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timer/ticker.dart';

part 'timer_event.dart';
part 'timer_state.dart';

class TimerBloc extends Bloc<TimerEvent, TimerState> {
  final Ticker _ticker;
  int _duration;

  StreamSubscription<int>? _tickerSubscription;

  TimerBloc({required Ticker ticker, required int duration})
      : _ticker = ticker,
        _duration = duration,
        super(TimerInital(duration)) {
    on<TimerStarted>(_onStarted);
    on<_TimerTicked>(_onTicked);
    on<TimerPaused>(_onPaused);
    on<TimerResumed>(_onResumed);
    on<TimerReset>(_onReset);
    on<TimerChanged>(_onChanged);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  void _onStarted(TimerStarted event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    emit(TimerRunInProgress(event.duration));
    _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
    _tickerSubscription = _ticker
        .tick(ticks: event.duration)
        .listen((duration) => add(_TimerTicked(duration: duration)));
  }

  void _onTicked(_TimerTicked event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    emit(
      event.duration > 0
          ? TimerRunInProgress(event.duration)
          : TimerRunComplete(),
    );
  }

  void _onPaused(TimerPaused event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    if (state is TimerRunInProgress) {
      _tickerSubscription?.pause();
      emit(TimerRunPause(state.duration));
    }
    ;
  }

  void _onReset(TimerReset event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
    emit(TimerInital(_duration));
  }

  void _onResumed(TimerResumed event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    if (state is TimerRunPause) {
      _tickerSubscription?.resume();
      emit(TimerRunInProgress(state.duration));
    }
  }

  void _onChanged(TimerChanged event, Emitter<TimerState> emit) {
    if (state is TimerInital) {
      _duration = event.duration;
      emit(TimerDurationChange(_duration));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about changing TimerChanged to hold the previous TimerInitial as part of the object declared properties?